# Finding index values in a pandas data frame where columns are the same

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame with multiple columns where the index is a timestamp, three others are phase number indicators and the rest is just data. What I am trying to do is find when the three indicator columns are in the same phase type which consists of one of a list of numbers.

```
So my data frame looks like this:
Index                    PhaseA   PhaseB   PhaseC   DataCol
01/07/2013  00:00:00     400      415      425      1.2
01/07/2013  00:01:00     415      420      410      1.2
01/07/2013  00:02:00     415      423      415      1.2
01/07/2013  00:03:00     415      423      420      1.2
01/07/2013  00:04:00     415      423      423      1.2
01/07/2013  00:05:00     415      423      425      1.2
```

So in this simplified case i'm looking for when all three phase numbers are values of 415, 423, 427 and 432. This means that the rows I want to get in this instance are the 2 minute one and the 4 minute one.

I am preferably looking for the dates and times that this has happended so I can then investigate it further using the other data columns. In addition this is unlikely to be only time I have to do this so being able to change the numbers and columns i'm interested in would be good.

So far i've managed to get it to work with code similar to:

```
df[ (df["PhaseA"] == (415))]

and then for multiple ones:

df[(df["PhaseA"] == (415))|(df["PhaseA"] == (420))]
```

But this is going to get very messy quickly and will be difficult to modify later on.

Any help would be appreciated as I'm relatively new to python and programming in general.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
mask = df[['PhaseA','PhaseB','PhaseC']].isin([415,423,427,432]).all(axis=1)
df.ix[mask]
```

---

For example,

```
In [51]: mask = df[['PhaseA','PhaseB','PhaseC']].isin([415,423,427,432]).all(axis=1)
In [52]: mask 
Out[52]: 
Index
2013-01-07 00:00:00    False
2013-01-07 00:01:00    False
2013-01-07 00:02:00     True
2013-01-07 00:03:00    False
2013-01-07 00:04:00     True
2013-01-07 00:05:00    False
dtype: bool

In [53]: df.ix[mask]
```

yields

```
Out[53]: 
                     PhaseA  PhaseB  PhaseC  DataCol
Index                                               
2013-01-07 00:02:00     415     423     415      1.2
2013-01-07 00:04:00     415     423     423      1.2
```

---

`DataFrame.isin` will be added to v0.13 of Pandas. Without `DataFrame.isin` you can create the `mask` with

```
mask = df[['PhaseA','PhaseB','PhaseC']].applymap(set([415,423,427,]).__contains__).all(axis=1)
```

Comment: Thanks @unutbu for the reply. This seems like it will do what I want but I get an error as apparently DataFrame doesn't have an attribute named isin. Is this because I am on 0.12 pandas as from looking I believe isin for DataFrames is not yet in the release. Is there a way to do it without isin?

Comment: You are right! Sorry about that. I've added code above to show how `mask` can be defined without `isin`.